# How to chain internally within a class?

Tags: php, fluent-interface

I wonder if we can chain 'internally' within a class itself? For instance, I have these two classes,

First class,

```
class Object1
{
    public $item;
    public $obj2;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->obj2 = new Object2();
    }

    public function chain1()
    {
        $this->item = 'Chain1 ';

        return $this; 
    }

    public function chain2()
    {

        //$this->item = $this->obj2->chain3(); // works ok.
        $this->item = $this->obj2->chain3()->chain1(); // how to chain yourself?

        return $this;
    }
}
```

second class,

```
class Object2
{
    public $item;
    public function chain3()
    {
        $this->item = 'Chain 3 ';
        return $this; 
    }

    public function chain4()
    {
        $this->item = 'Chain4 ';
        return $this;
    }
}

$obj1 = new Object1();
print_r($obj1->chain2()->item);
```

error,

```
atal error: Call to undefined method Object2::chain1() in C:...
```

I need to chain `chain1()` in the class `Ojbect1()` itself.

```
$this->item = $this->obj2->chain3()->chain1();
```

Is it possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible and neither does it make sense. What would you stand to gain? Please don't tell me "it would look cooler in the editor".

Comment: chain3() returns an Object2 object; so how can you expect that to then call a method in the Object1 class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain a method by returning `$this` from it:

```
class foo
{
    public $foo;
    public function yayThisChains()
    {
        return $this->chain()->chain2()->doIt();
    }
    private function doIt()
    {
        $this->foo = 'bar';
        return $this;
    }
    private function chain2() { return $this; }
    private function chain() { return $this; }
}

$foo = new foo();
echo $foo->yayThisChains()->foo;
```

The problem is you are trying to chain two different objects using the same `$this`. You could extend your classes so `$this` refers to the same class instead of building `object2` in `object1` through constructor:

```
class Object2 extends Object1
```

Comment: @PeeHaa fix'd. only two years later.